# TS adds non-existent props to objects having call signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, if the type of an object has a call signature, there will be many more methods and attributes (like `apply`, `length`, ...), which are from the prototype of Function. Now that ES2015 has added Proxy to the language, we may camouflage an object with other prototype into a function, how to keep TS from adding non-existent props?

For example,

```
interface AA {
  (): void;
  abc: number;
}
const aa: AA = new Proxy({ abc: 12345 }, {
  apply() { console.log('aa~') }
});
```

In my mind, the proto of `aa` is `Object` and only has prop `abc`, however, TS will prompt other props.

Comment: If it's callable typescript assumes it inherits function automatically. Just like any `[]` is an `Array` or `{}` inherist `Object`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You're right. However, I'm still consider if I could find a way to provide the correct type hinting, as I'm writing a lib for users.

Comment: I am 99% sure I saw a ticket on github requesting a way to pick just the signature from a type and exclude all the stuff from `Function`. You might try intersecting the type with something that contains the members of function but in such a way to make them uncallable..